# send touch events to another view

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a UIView ontop of a mapview. Currently the UIView is handling the touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded. I need to make it so that the UIView is able to send touch events to the mapView. I have been looking at gesturerecognizers, but so far have had no luck. Has this been done before?, and if so, how can i do this?

my view heiarchy in storyboard

view

- mapView
- UIView

a little more clarification.
My UIView is used to draw from touch inputs. I have a button that enables and disables the drawing, but the touch events are still bieng handled in the UIView. I want to make it so that when i disable drawing by pressing my button. The user interacts with the mapview instead of the UIView.
I have tried setting userInteractionEnabled = NO in the UIView, but then i can't regain control in that view when the draw button is pressed again.

Comment: You need to characterize the types of touches you want to handle in the top view, and which you want to handle in the map view. You shouldn't directly forward `touches_____:` methods, but perhaps you can translate touches on the top view into calls to other methods on the map view.

Comment: i think that is what im trying to do. my class handling the touches for the UIView is a delegate of the mapview because i need to get certain objects from the mapview. i need to make a method in my mapview class, that takes the touches, i can call from the UIview class, and handles them using the native ios gesture and touch events.